# is Location.X equal to Top,Left in a ListBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am confused a little bit:

with a code like this: lets assume the list box is inside a panel and panel is inside a tableLayout and,etc...

```
 Point myLocation = PointToClient(myListBox.Location);
```

so it returns a Point.X and Point.Y,  but what are these X and Y ? are they X and Y of the Top,Left corner of my list box according to the whole form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `Location.X = Left` and `Location.Y = Top`. `Left` and `Top` are just shortcuts provided for convenience.

Comment: "Left and Right are just shortcuts provided for convenience."... thanks, you meant "left and top" , right? in the second part of your sentence...

Answer (score 1):

Your call to PointToClient is incorrect.  PointToClient takes a point in screen coordinates and converts them to coordinates relative to the control you are calling PointToClient on. myListBox.Location is returning client coordinates relative to its container, not screen coordinates.

If you are looking to convert to screen coordinates, look at using PointToScreen().

Comment: hmm...yes I think you are correct. I think this one is correct, what do you think:
Point locationOnForm = lstSelected.FindForm().PointToClient(lstSelected.Parent.PointToScreen(lstSelected.Location));